# Two words connected by AND: Singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

If I write the following sentence:

"Any hypothesis generation and knowledge extraction *require*  efficient, fast responding graphical solutions."

Is it "require" or "requires"?

Comment: With the use of "any", you'd want to use the conjunction "or" rather than "and", and then use "requires".

Comment: What @CanadianYankee said (Imagine: "Any rose or daisy smell sweet"—the problem is not with the number of the verb!). But of course if you delete "Any," then it's plural.

Comment: Beautiful! Unfortunately I am not an English native speaker, so these kind of questions are still difficult to me. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think _hypothesis generation_ and _knowledge extraction_ can really be treated as a singular composite whole (unlike _bacon and eggs_, _health and safety_ in typical contexts), so singular agreement isn't available even with notional concord. I'd substitute 'both' for 'any'.

Comment: The any is used in a sense of "Whenever someone wants to do hypothesis generation or knowledge extraction, this will require...."